# Unable to start server in development environment

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-on-rails-5

i am using rbenv. my rails version is 5.1.1. my ruby version is 2.4.1.
When i run rails s command i got following one liner error.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i have tried to reinstall ruby, try to start server using bundle exec rails s, bundle update but still getting error. Only rails -v command is working fine any other rails command is not working.

Comment: Is there anything in the log?

Comment: i have checked development.log and it is empty.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on a new rails app? I ask because this would show if it's an issue with your environment/installation, or with the specific rails application you are trying to run.

Comment: I have another project and that project working fine on same machine

Comment: OK, so it's something in the app ... Can you try to produce a **minimal** example of it? Maybe you have a circular dependency, or are using a broken gem. Try deleting/commenting things out.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, there's not much we can do to help...

Comment: @TomLord same code is working on other team member machines.

Comment: Can you create a new project `rails new myApp -O` and try to run it? I just think you should rebuild one of native gem. Which one -- I don't know

Comment: @TomLord i have verified that when i add gem 'fillable-pdf', '~> 0.1.1', github: 'aafaq-hassan/fillable-pdf' in gem file error accusers and when i comment out project start working.